# Mathematica Partial Fraction Decomposition full steps

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I hope to get full steps instead of getting the result. Any ways to do so?

Comment: Try WolframAlpha instead.

Comment: Mathematica's goal is to provide a solution/answer, and it may use intermediate steps that are very different from the methods we humans tend to use. Even if you could get access to Mathematica's step-by-step solution, you may not be able to understand them easily because they may involve higher math than strictly necessary, as well as precomputed heuristics.

Comment: If it's homework, one possibility might be to work out the steps on paper.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica does not provide step-by-step solutions. The algorithms that it uses are generally not ones that people would use in working through a problem. However, for a limited number of problems, you can get step-by-step solutions by calling WolframAlpha from Mathematica. For example, `WolframAlpha["partial fractions of (5x-4)/(x^2-x-2)"]` The subpod of interest is

```
WolframAlpha["partial fractions of (5x-4)/(x^2-x-2)", {{"Result", 2}, 
  "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Result__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use [`Apart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apart.html), e.g., `(5 x - 4)/(x^2 - x - 2) // Apart`